# woocommerce add variations to a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hope someone can point me in the right direction, we have a custom plugin for wooommerce, developer left us!!! 
The custom plugin is a custom post type, actually a bundle with many custom weights making up the product, to keep it simple think of it has a cake with ingredients.

The owner now wants the product (custom product type) to have 3 variations.
This will never change always 3 no more no less.

I can find tuitions on creating custom product types, but nothing is out there calling variations into a custom product type.

I need to get the basic workings correct so as i approach other developers i can gauge what is going on.

I know i am being vague but i cannot post the plugin on here. 
I keep seeing reference to the Class: WC_Product_Variable 
Do i need the plugin to add a function for variables to be switched on as such, with a call to a variable function file.

Also calling an add to cart variable file.

Can some of the code be used from the woocommerce file class-wc-product-variation.php

help and guidance aprreciated

Comment: What is different from regular variable products? I'm just wondering if you really *need* a custom product type.

Comment: There are many calls to custom reports, believe me it could not use standard variable products, Internally in our plugin admin has to input many extra fields